# const method modifies object using reference

Tags: c++

The following code calls a `const` method passing a reference to a member, which is then modified.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  int i;
  A(int _x) : i(_x) { }
  void calc(int& j, const int value) const { j = value; }
  void set1() { calc(i, 1); }
};

int main()
{
  A a(3);
  std::cout << a.i << std::endl;
  a.set1();
  std::cout << a.i << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles with gcc 6.4.0, and with clang 5.0.2, with no warnings.

Is the code legal?
The `const` method `calc` is able to modify the object, when called from a `non-const` method.

Comment: Unless your object isn't `const`, the `const` specifier doesn't make any difference. If `a` was `const`, you would not be able to call `A::set1`.

Comment: in `void calc` try `i = value;`. Then you will suddenly get `error: assignment of member ‘A::i’ in read-only object`.... or try to set `const int& j`. Then you will get `error: assignment of read-only reference ‘j’`

Comment: This is a good example why you shouldn't expose raw fields as public-accessible members.

Comment: @YurySchkatula making it private doesn't change the behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that having a "const pointer" like `const Thing*` or a "const reference" like `const Thing&` does NOT mean that the const-qualified object cannot change while you have the pointer/reference.  It only means that you can't use that particular pointer/reference as a way of changing it. But there could be other names, pointers, or references that do allow changing it.

A couple of examples:

```
void f1(const int& arg1, int& arg2) {
    std::cout << "arg1 before: " << arg1 << "\n";
    arg2 = 4;
    std::cout << "arg1 after: " << arg1 << "\n"; // same thing?
}
```

`f1` might look as though it must always print the same value in the "before" and "after" lines.  But not if someone passes the same `int` object to both arguments:

```
void call_f1() {
    int n = 7;
    f1(n, n); // Prints before 7, after 4!
}
```

Or if a function call comes between two uses of a const reference, that can similarly change a variable in some way:

```
void something_else();
void f2(const int& arg) {
    std::cout << "arg before: " << arg << "\n";
    something_else();
    std::cout << "arg after: " << arg << "\n";
}

int n = 2;
void something_else() { n = 8; }

void call_f2() {
    f2(n); // Prints before 2, after 8!
}
```

So it's true that in your `void A::calc(int& j, const int value) const` function, the `this` pointer is `const A* const`, which means you can't change the `A` object *using the `this` pointer*.  But there can still be other ways to change it, like here you have an `int& j` reference to non-const object.  If it so happens that `j` refers to a subobject of `*this`, then modifying `j` is a valid way of modifying the subobject of `*this`.  This is similar to my `f1` example above, where `arg1` can't be used to change the referenced `int`, but `arg2` can, and if they refer to the same `int`, this means `arg1` has changed.

---

The case is slightly different when a variable is *defined* with the `const` qualifier in the first place.  If we write

```
const A a(3);
```

then we do get a guarantee that (except during the constructor and destructor), the object can't be changed in any way.  The language will usually prevent you from accidentally trying, like with `a.set1()`, but even if you try `const_cast` tricks, any actual change would then be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 8):

`const` qualifier on a member function applies to the `*this` instance.

In `calc()`, `this` is a pointer to const `A`, but the parameter `j` is taken by non-const reference, so this is perfectly standard behaviour.

Now, if in `calc` you tried to assign to `this->i`, the code would not compile.

```
void A::calc(const int value) const
{
    i = value; // Compilation error here: i is a data member of a const instance
}
```

In the same way, if `set1` was made a const member function, then, the code would not compile (because it would try to bind `this->i` to a parameter taken by non-const reference)

Answer (score 6):

Sure. Marking the method `const` just makes `*this` `const`, i.e. the function promises not to modify the object *by writing through `this`*.

It's still possible to modify the object through other means (assuming they're not marked `const` as well, such as `int& j` in your example).

Comment: *other means* like casting `this`

Comment: @GauravSehgal No, I mean using other pointers or references that refer to (parts of) the object. Casting away constness is naughty (and quickly leads to UB if the object is actually `const`).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Declaring a method `const` merely means that `this` is const. However, your method does not (directly) modify `this` or any members of `this`.  Consider this contrived, albeit correct example:

```
struct foo {
    int value;
    void modify_const(foo& f) const { f.value = 5; }
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    f.value = 3;
    f.modify_const(f);
}
```

The method does not modify `this`, and the parameter is declared as non-const, thus calling `f.modify_const(f);` on a `const f` will fail due to the parameter being passed as non-const.

Comment: You can't call `f.modify_const(f)` on a `const foo f;`. Did you mean to write `void modify_const(foo& f) const`?

Comment: @aschepler ups yes, thanks for spotting that silly mistake, without that `const` the example is pointless ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just shows you are never safe. A `const` qualifier doesn't guarantee the value can never change.

Try it like this, and you can do really nasty things:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    const int i;
    void calc(int& j, const int value) const { j = value; }
public:
    A(int _x) : i(_x) { }
    void set1() const { calc(*const_cast<int*>(&i), 1); }
    int getI() const { return i; }
};

int main()
{
    const A a(3);
    std::cout << a.getI() << std::endl;
    a.set1();
    std::cout << a.getI() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is UB, is that what you meant?

Comment: @PasserBy What I meant is that `const` does not mean there is no way to modify a value. There is always a way. You cannot simply label something `const` and assume it's value will never change.

Comment: Within the rules of the language, a `const` object really doesn't change, changing it is UB. I'm not sure if calling that a way to modify an object is accurate

Comment: @PasserBy true, but in this case I don't agree with the definition. The standard supplies the tools and the implementation works. Yet because it is unwanted, they stamp it "undefined behavior". In this case I would rather interpret UB as "unwanted business". In the mean time this `const_cast` still works, so ignoring this would be burying our head in the sand. There's almost always a way to modify a `const` object.